# In TDD, should returning class of public method be unit tested independently?

Tags: design, object-oriented, architecture, unit-testing, testing

Suppose that I have a class that is returned only as a byproduct of another "main" class. I am using a Test Driven Development (TDD) workflow.

Should this byproduct class be unit tested independently or should I be considered as an implementation detail of the "main" class I am testing?

---

## Example:

Suppose I have the following implementation requirements:

- Whenever the `Bakery` bake with more than one egg, flour, and bakes right after, the baking result is delicious and its color is golden brown.

To satisfy them, I have implemented the following test and code:

```cs
public class BakeryTests()
{

    [Test]
    public void Baking_EnoughEggsAndFlourAddedAndBaked_BakingIsGood()
    {
        Bakery bakery = new Bakery();
        bakery.Add(new Egg());
        bakery.Add(new Egg());
        bakery.Add(new Flour());
        bakery.Bake();

        BakingResult result = bakery.GetResultColor();

        Assert.AreEqual(BakingColor.GoldenBrown, result.Color):
        Assert.AreEqual(BakingFlavor.Delicious, result.Flavor):
    }

}
```

```cs
public class Bakery()
{
    public void AddIgredient(IIgredient igredient)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Bake()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public BakingResult GetResult()
    {
        // ...
        BakingResult bakingResult = new BakingResult();
        bakingResult.Color = BakingColor.GoldenBrown;
        bakingResult.Flavor = BakingFlavor.Delicious;
        return bakingResult;
    }

}
```

In this example `BakingResult` is the byproduct class of the "main" class `Bakery`. It only exists as a way for Bakery to communicate an output for the consumer of its public API.

### Now consider the following alternative implementation of the same requirements:

```cs
public class BakeryTests()
{

    [Test]
    public void Baking_EnoughEggsAndFlourAddedAndBaked_BakingIsGood
    {
        Bakery bakery = new Bakery();
        bakery.Add(new Egg());
        bakery.Add(new Egg());
        bakery.Add(new Flour());
        bakery.Bake();

        Assert.AreEqual(BakingColor.GoldenBrown, bakery.GetResultColor()):
        Assert.AreEqual(BakingFlavor.Delicious, bakery.GetResultFlavor()):
    }

}
```

```cs
public class Bakery()
{
    public void AddIgredient(IIgredient igredient)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void Bake()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public BakingColor GetResultColor()
    {
        // ...
        return BakingColor.GoldenBrown;
    }

    public BakingFlavor GetResultFlavor()
    {
        // ...
        return BakingFlavor.Delicious;
    }

}
```

That implementation would implement the requirements just as well as the first implementation.

**In the first example, `BakingResult` was just a way of `Bakery` expressing its output in a more concise way.**

---

Assuming I choose that `BakingResult` is better suited than a primitive value type or than multiple methods each returning a quality of the result.

Is there any TDD guidelines or best practice that would suggest that it should be unit tested independently, or should it be tested inherently as part of the tests of `Bakery`, since it could be seen as a "implementation" detail of Bakery?

Comment: This feels to me as more question about returned "cake" being a value type Cake or primitive type string. It has nothing to do with testing or TDD.

Comment: The question is "If I decide to make cake a returning type, should it be united tested?"

Comment: Whether or not the return value is wrapped in a custom type should have no impact on your testing. If you're doing TDD, you write the test first and then implement based on that. If you're choosing an implementation and then deciding how best to test it, you're not doing TDD.

Comment: I have just changed the naming of the class from `Cake` to `BakingResult` to disassociate the idea that Cake is an independent business entity in the example.

Comment: When you write a test, you define the public API of your code. You cannot write a test without a public API defined. `Whether or not the return value is wrapped in a custom type should have no impact on your testing` -> that is false. The return value is part of the public API. My question is regarding the choice of making the return value its own class. In that case, should this class be also covered by tests? This question is arising in the public API definition phase before any code has been written and hence it is pertinent to TDD.

Comment: I have added a clarification that the question is being asked on the hypothesis that `BakingResult` was chosen over the primitive type `string` implementation. As far as the public API definition is concerned, `BakingResult` is expected as the output of `GetResult()`.

Comment: You test behavior. Does your returning type have behavior to test? If yes, then test the behavior. If not, then there's nothing to test that you aren't already testing for.

Comment: @Albuquerque you're missing my point. Write the test to test the behaviour you want to test. Then implement it. That's it. Where that behaviour ends up being implemented comes out in the wash. It's driven by the test and the test is what defines that public API. If you're worrying about what classes and functions and properties need tests writing for them, you're doing it backwards. In other words, the answer is "no," you don't need to explicitly write tests for a simple DTO that should already have been covered by the test you wrote in the first place.

Comment: @AntP Thanks for the clarification. It is much more clear now!

Comment: This question is fluctuating between -1, 0 and +1 votes. It currently does not have any close votes. Any more comments on what is wrong with the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When testing, you are testing the expected state of the end result of your test.  **Whether you wrap your response in an object has everything to do with your API design and not your test.**  You can ask the obvious followup question about whether it is better API design or not.  In general, the more robust your API is, the more clear the state is.

For example, the text `"good"` means something to humans, but to a machine it is as opaque as any other four letter word.  Text in general is a problematic return type because it is easy to be inconsistent.  Do we need to worry about capital letters?  What about common mispellings?  What about synonyms?  Is `"ok"` equivalent to `"good"`?

In this particular example you could have returned a `bool` and everything would have been good.  That said, I doubt that is all you want at the moment.  I'm sure there can be varying qualities of acceptable for this scenario.

In that case your test should ensure that the `BakingResult` has all the qualities you expect.  For example:

- `result.Succes` should be true
- `result.Color` should be `CookingColors.GoldenBrown`

Now, if you choose to use `BakingResult`, you would need to add a few more tests for the result class itself.  For example, testing equality would be necessary for the examples you gave.  By default in most object oriented programming languages, you would need to tell the `BakingResult` object to tell if a new instance of the object was equivalent to the current one.  Your first test will fail until you override the method that checks equality to use the values of the object rather than the memory address the instance lives at.

---

The updates to the OP don't fundamentally change my answer.  The general idea is that the `BakingResult` is in the final state you expect.  For example, you have one test for ensuring there are sufficient eggs and flour and that test is good.  Now you have to write tests for insufficient  ingredients.

Example:

```
[Test]
public void Baking_NotEnoughEggs()
{
    Bakery bakery = new Bakery();
    bakery.Add(new Egg());
    bakery.Add(new Flour());
    bakery.Bake();

    Assert.AreEqual(BakingColor.PastyWhite, bakery.GetResultColor()):
    Assert.AreEqual(BakingFlavor.Chalky, bakery.GetResultFlavor()):
}
```

Similarly, if you had enough eggs, but no flour you would need to test that condition as well.

```
[Test]
public void Baking_NoFlour()
{
    Bakery bakery = new Bakery();
    bakery.Add(new Egg());
    bakery.Add(new Egg());
    bakery.Bake();

    Assert.AreEqual(BakingColor.Yellow, bakery.GetResultColor()):
    Assert.AreEqual(BakingFlavor.Eggy, bakery.GetResultFlavor()):
}
```

In other words, you simply need to test that the values affected by your test are in the final state you expect.

Comment: I have changed the example in the question to one that does not raise the concerns you have pointed in your question. Indeed, the string implementation and the equality were issues in the previous example, but I think they somewhat divert from the question of testing or not BakingResult. That being said, I think that your sentence `Now, if you choose to use BakingResult, you would need to add a few more tests for the result class itself.` is still a valid answer to the question.

Answer (score -3):

In TDD you have to write a test before you write any code.

I guess there's no rule saying you can't write a single test:

```
myApp.WorksCorrectly() == true
```

And then code untill it passes. But I think we would all agree its against the spirit of the approach